# Solving recurrence equations for a given algorithm with FLOOR

Tags: algorithm

Hello I am completely lost as to how to find the recurrence equation related to the given algorithm.

```
C(i, j, x)
    if i=j then
        if A[i] = x
        return YES
    else
        return NO
    else
        if C(i, floor((i+j)/2), x) = YES
            return YES
        else
            return C(floor((i+j)/2) + 1, j, x)
```

I get that for the if statements you would count as 1. But I am lost as to how to get the recurrence equation for the recursive call return C(floor((i+j)/2) +1, j, x)

MY end attempt would be t(n) = T(n/2 +1) + 3;
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`C` makes two recursive calls when the first returns `NO`, so the recurrence should be

```
T(n) = T(ceiling(n/2)) + T(floor(n/2)) + 3.
```

Here I've worked out the arguments of `T` on the right hand side by trying some small examples.

```
C(1, 5, x) => C(1, 3, x) and C(4, 5, x)
C(1, 6, x) => C(1, 3, x) and C(4, 6, x)
```

In truth, though, if you're about to apply the Master Theorem to a recurrence like this one, then the precise statement involving floor and ceiling hardly matters. A more general statement of the Master Theorem, [Akra--Bazzi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), states that, under all circumstances that you are likely to encounter, a little fuzziness in the arguments of the recursive calls will not change the asymptotic analysis. In this case specifically, `T` is big-Theta of `T'` defined by

```
T'(n) = T'(n/2) + T'(n/2) + 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to answer the question 'Does the array include x?'. It searches the lower half of the array recursively, then the upper half of the array recursively until it finds X or has checked all the indices, and can say it is not in the array.

So it is T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 3, which is O(n) by Master Theorem. Since you have to check all of the indices in the worst case to say 'Yes' or 'No'.

Consider the case where x is not in the array (we'll just use A[i] = i for an array with 10 indices 0 to 9)

```
x = 10 
i = 0, j = 9
0. C(0, 9, 10)
    i != j
1. C(0,4,10)
    i != j
2. C(0,2,10)
    i != j
3. C(0,1,10)
    i != j
4. C(0,0)
    i == j
    A[i] != 10: Return NO.
From 3. else:
5. C(1,1, 10)
    i == j
    A[i] != 10: Return NO
From 2. else:
6. C(2,2,10)
    i == j
    A[i] != 10: Return NO
From 1. else:
7. C(3,4,10)
    i != j
8. C(3,3,10)
    i == j
    A[i] != 10: Return NO
From 7. else:
9. C(4,4,10)
    i == j
    A[i] != 10: Return NO
From 0. else:
10. C(5, 9, 10)
    i != j      
11. C(5, 7, 10)
    i != j
12. C(5, 6, 10)
    i != j
13. C(5, 5, 10)
    i == j
    A[i] != 10: Return NO      
From 12. else:
14. C(6, 6, 10)
    i == j
    A[i] != 10: Return NO      
From 11. else:
15. C(6, 7, 10)
        i != j
16. C(6, 6, 10)
    i == j          
    A[i] != 10: Return NO      
From 15. else:
17. C(7, 7, 10)
        i == j
    A[i] != 10: Return NO      
From 10. else:
18. C(8, 9, 10)
    i != j
19. C(8, 8, 10)
        i == j
    A[i] != 10: Return NO      
From 18. else:
20. C(9, 9, 10)
    i == j
    A[i] != 10: Return NO      
10. Recieves No from all branches, returns No
 0. Recieves No from all branches, returns No.
```

Which winds up resulting in 20 recursive calls, and you can see the algorithm had to check each index to say '10 is not in the array'.